# Replace characters in string R

Tags: r, gsub

Trying to figure out how to select particular subsets of a character string. I want to convert

```
"OTU_511><-><size=54><-><" to "OTU_511;size=54;"
```

I can successfully remove everything after the OTU ID using the following code:

```
gsub("([^>]*).*", "\\1", tree$tip.label)
```

However, it'd be great to replace those characters with ";" instead. Thanks for any tips you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

If the pattern is consistently `><-><` then you can use the following.

```
x <- "OTU_511><-><size=54><-><"
gsub("><-><", ";", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "OTU_511;size=54;"
```

Comment: And the `stringi` equivalent:  `stri_replace_all_fixed(x, "><-><", ";")` if you're into that